# SharePoint groups as audiences don't refresh after membership changes

Tags: audiences

We've seen this issue where a group is used as an audience when the group membership changes (AD Groups) the audience doesn't pick the new members until the group is manually removed from the audiences, save the change and then re-added.

Is there a good practice to have the audiences recompiled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User profile audiences are defaultly configured to compile weekly. This can be altered in Central Administration by going to Monitoring -> Review Job Definitions -> User Profile Service Application - Audience Compilation Job. Edit the schedule as desired.